# Access ng-model from one directive to other directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so i have that template in first directive

```
<tr ng-repeat="node in myprops.List">
        <td>{{node.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td>{{node.endDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td>{{node.workInHours }}</td>
        <td><label type="button" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="setIndex($index)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{myprops.id}}">edit</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="onClick()" ng-model="node.selected" ></td>
    </tr>
```

and in that directive i have controller who has function setIndex(index)..
so when i click the button its open that modal

```
<form name="myForm">
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="sDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="eDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                        <input type="number" ng-model="hours"  required>
                    </form>
```

and that modal is in other directive template.. so i need when i click the button and open modal that what is in array with that $index to be add on ng-model on model ..sDate..eDate and hours ...
in short i need to access that ng model which is in one directive template from another controller in other directive

Comment: Get rid of using bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: Like i said i am new in angularjs  :( and i don't have time to learn how to use angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: Well you are going to have easier time than trying to do what you are doing now. That's why it was created in the first place. And actually looks like you might be using angular-material in which case you shouldn't need bootstrap at all

Comment: You need to learn how to use tools you are using. jQuery Bootstrap plugins is wrong tool, you will have problems with it anyway, so better listen good advice now.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass model object from main controller to the modal directive controller, then after modifying it by actions in modal returning this object to previous controller and assign new data from modal

E.g ([ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)):

```
function MainController($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.model = {};

  $scope.onClick = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     // params
     controller: ModalController;
     resolve: {data: function() {return $scope.model}}
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
      $scope.model = data
    })
  }
}

function ModalController($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
  // actions
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.saveForm = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give example, cuz i am new in angularjs